# Java RegEx backreference not working

Tags: java, regex

In java I tried to replace **.JPG.json** part with **.JPG**, saving letter case ( sometimes it maybe .jpg.json)

My Code :

```
String Path="MyImage.JPG.json";
Result=Path.replaceFirst("/(.jpg)\\.json/i","$1");
```

But it returns :
**MyImage.JPG.json**

Instead of:
**MyImage.JPG**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `/` slashes. In java, you don't need to include `/` as a regex delimiter. And also you must need to escape the dots. To do a case-insensitive match, add `(?i)` modifier at the first.

```
Path.replaceFirst("(?i)(\\.jpg)\\.json", "$1");
```

OR

You could use lookbehind assertion also.

```
Path.replaceFirst("(?i)(?<=\\.jpg)\\.json", "");
```

`(?<=\\.jpg)` Asserts that the string going to be matched must be preceded by `.jpg`. If yes then match only the following `.json` string. Replacing the matched `.json` string with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command. It should work for you:

```
Path.replaceFirst("(?i)(\\.jpg)\\.json","$1")
```